# Why does ASP.NET Core API scaffold [HttpGet] synchronous, but the other actions async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Im using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Controller scaffolding with EntityFrameworkCore.
The actions generated look like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Todo> GetTodos()
    {
        return _context.Todos;
    }

    // GET: api/Todos/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTodo([FromRoute] int? id)
    {
        ...
        var todo = await _context.Todos.FindAsync(id);
        ...

        return Ok(todo);
    }
```

Can someone explain why the GetTodos() Action uses sync execution and when I should change it to an async action.
Lets say I only want to return a Dto Object:

```
// GET: api/Todos
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TodoDto> GetTodos()
{
    return _context.Todos.Select(x => new TodoDto() { Title = x.Title });
}
```

Should I then async cast to a List?

```
// GET: api/Todos
[HttpGet]
public Task<List<TodoDto>> GetTodos()
{
    return _context.Todos.Select(x => new TodoDto() { Title = x.Title }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Probably as examples of what's possible?

Comment: or you can use `Task.FromResult(...)`

Comment: yes its just an example change to return task